# Differences between rows using different row as start

Tags: r, dataframe, plyr, panel-data

I have the following dataframe in R:

```
ID          year    event_year
432674326   2000    NA
432674326   2001    NA
432674326   2002    NA
432674326   2003    NA
432674326   2004    NA
432674326   2005    2005_1
432674326   2006    NA
432674326   2007    NA
432674326   2008    NA
432876423   2003    NA
432876423   2004    NA
432876423   2005    NA
432876423   2006    NA
432876423   2007    2007_82
432876423   2008    NA
432876423   2009    NA
432876423   2010    NA
```

And I would like to create a column that calculates the difference between my event year and the respective year on each row. The outcome should look like the following:

```
ID          year    event_year  timediff
432674326   2000    NA          -5
432674326   2001    NA          -4
432674326   2002    NA          -3
432674326   2003    NA          -2
432674326   2004    NA          -1
432674326   2005    2005_1       0
432674326   2006    NA           1
432674326   2007    NA           2
432674326   2008    NA           3
432876423   2003    NA          -4
432876423   2004    NA          -3
432876423   2005    NA          -2
432876423   2006    NA          -1
432876423   2007    2007_82      0
432876423   2008    NA           1
432876423   2009    NA           2
432876423   2010    NA           3
```

I was trying with plyr but I can not fix the base year to the event year. I can only use a certain lag as below, which does not give me the intended result.

```
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(timediff = year - lag(year))
```

Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do this by subtracting the row that correspond to non_NA with `row_number()`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    mutate(timediff = row_number() - which(!is.na(event_year)))
#          ID  year event_year timediff
#       <int> <int>      <chr>    <int>
#1  432674326  2000       <NA>       -5
#2  432674326  2001       <NA>       -4
#3  432674326  2002       <NA>       -3
#4  432674326  2003       <NA>       -2
#5  432674326  2004       <NA>       -1
#6  432674326  2005     2005_1        0
#7  432674326  2006       <NA>        1
#8  432674326  2007       <NA>        2
#9  432674326  2008       <NA>        3
#10 432876423  2003       <NA>       -4
#11 432876423  2004       <NA>       -3
#12 432876423  2005       <NA>       -2
#13 432876423  2006       <NA>       -1
#14 432876423  2007    2007_82        0
#15 432876423  2008       <NA>        1
#16 432876423  2009       <NA>        2
#17 432876423  2010       <NA>        3
```